# C# regex syntax

Tags: c#, regex, file, io

My REGEX works [here](http://regex101.com/r/jO5wP5) but not in code. I have never done REGEX in C# so I might be missing something syntactically. Any ideas?

**Basically I am trying to read through a file `old.txt` and if a line matches my REGEX then I want to replace it. What I would like to do is read each line, check it with my REGEX (if it doesn't match, fine; if it does, change it) then write THAT line to another file `new.txt`**

As of right now I am writing to the console for testing

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String line;

        try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\old.txt");

            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null)
            {
                //check lines
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s?(set)\s*(\w+):?(\d)\s+;?(.*)?"))
                {
                    line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s?(set)\s*(\w+):?(\d)\s+;?(.*)?", "$1 $2:$3     :Integer // $4");
                }

                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s?(string)\s*(\w+)\((\d)\)\s*;(.*)"))
                {
                    line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s?(string)\s*(\w+)\((\d)\)\s*;(.*)", "$1 $2($3) :array [0..$3] of AnsiChar; // $4");
                }
                //write the lie to console window
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //Read the next line
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            //close the file
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is some of the input which gives you unexpected output, what is that output, and what do you expect?

Comment: Is there an exception???

Comment: @Sean You can see it in my link I provided. No, there is no exception

Comment: I did. I figured this warranted another question.

Comment: You should be using an online regex tester that states it will work with C#/.Net.

Comment: @AustinSalonen such as [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the overloads that include RegexOptions.  I can make your stuff work if I include [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Regex.IsMatch(given, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Regex.Replace(given, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

[MSDN Regex.IsMatch Method (String, String, RegexOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktzf2d23%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[MSDN Regex.Replace Method (String, String, String, RegexOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)